# Install rgdal and rgeos on Azure Databricks

Tags: r, azure, gdal, azure-databricks, geos

I cannot install rgdal and rgeos on Databricks, any suggestions?

```
configure: error: gdal-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgdal’
* removing ‘/databricks/spark/R/lib/rgdal’

configure: error: geos-config not found or not executable.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgeos’
* removing ‘/databricks/spark/R/lib/rgeos’
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one way to install rgdal and rgeos on R on Azure Databricks. Step 1 and 2 needs to be done each time you start the cluster. Step 1 can be automated (see below) but step 2 needs to be executed manually in a separate script or be added to the top of your R script.

#### Step 1

You need to first install gdal and geos on the linux machines in your cluster. This can be done with bash script in a databricks notebook. The `%s` is the magic command that allows this cell to run a shell script.

```py
%sh
#!/bin/bash

#Start by updating everything
sudo apt-get update

##############
#### rgdal

#This installs gdal on the linux machine but not the R library (done in R script)
#See https://databricks.com/notebooks/rasterframes-notebook.html
sudo apt-get install -y gdal-bin libgdal-dev

#To be able to install the R library, you also need libproj-dev 
#See https://philmikejones.me/tutorials/2014-07-14-installing-rgdal-in-r-on-linux/
sudo apt-get install -y libproj-dev 

##############
#### rgeos

#This installs geos on the linux machine but not the R library (done in R script)
#See https://philmikejones.me/tutorials/2014-07-14-installing-rgdal-in-r-on-linux/
sudo apt install libgeos++dev
```

However, that is annoying to have to run manually each time, so you can create an init script that runs each time on startup of the cluster. So in a databricks *python* notebook, copy this code into a cell. Scripts in `dbfs:/databricks/init/<name_of_cluster>` will run on start-up for clusters with that name.

```sh
#This file creates a bash script called install_packages.sh. The cluster run this file on each startup.
# The bash script will be anything inside the variable script 

clusterName = "RStudioCluster"
script = """#!/bin/bash

#Start by updating everything
sudo apt-get update

##############
#### rgdal

#This installs gdal on the linux machine but not the R library (done in R script)
#See https://databricks.com/notebooks/rasterframes-notebook.html
sudo apt-get install -y gdal-bin libgdal-dev

#To be able to install the R library, you also need libproj-dev 
#See https://philmikejones.me/tutorials/2014-07-14-installing-rgdal-in-r-on-linux/
sudo apt-get install -y libproj-dev 

##############
#### rgeos

#This installs geos on the linux machine but not the R library (done in R script)
#See https://philmikejones.me/tutorials/2014-07-14-installing-rgdal-in-r-on-linux/
sudo apt install libgeos++dev

"""
dbutils.fs.put("dbfs:/databricks/init/%s/install_packages.sh" % clusterName, script, True)
```

#### Step 2

So far you have just installed gdal and geos on the linux machines in the cluster. In this step you will install the R package `rgdal`. Recent versions of `rgdal` however, are not compatible with the most recent version of `gdal` available with `apt-get`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51749860/installing-rgdal-backdate-rgdal-version-versus-update-gdal-version-and-how) for more details and alternative ways to solve this, but if you are ok with an older version of `rgdal` then the easiest workaround is to install version 1.2-20 of `rgdal`.  You do that in an databricks *R* notebook or in the Rstudio databricks app like this:

```r
require(devtools)
install_version("rgdal", version="1.2-20")
install.packages("rgeos")
```

#### Setup done

Then you can import these libraries like usual:

```r
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)
```

Comment: Hi, When I run step 1, I get the error:

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package libgeos++dev

Comment: I solved this by doing  `libgeos++-dev` from here https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libgeos++-dev

Comment: @ThelceBear, thanks for your answer that helped me to install rgeos and rgdal. Having a similar issue with  'units' on Databricks. Any idea how to solve it? Happy to raise a new question..

Comment: Sorry, it was only this that I was tasked to solve for a colleague